# Pass Value in Nested Parameter in Blazor Component

Tags: razor, parameters, nested, blazor

How do i pass value in nested parameter. suppose i have a custom control called mycomponent

**mycomponent.Razor**

```
<label>
    
</label>
@code
{
   [Parameter]
    public TestBase Test { get; set; } = new TestBase();
}
```

**TestBase** Class

```
public class TestBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Cap { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Cap5 { get; set; }="hai"


    [Parameter]
    public string Cap2 { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public string Cap3 { get; set; }

}
```

**MyPage**

```
<mycomponent Test.Cap="my value">

</mycomponent>
```

**Test.Cap="my value"** is not working

What is the right way to pass value in nested Parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing `TestBase` into `MyComponent`, not trying to set a  value of `TestBase` in `MyComponent`.  Setting a default value for `Test` in `MyComponent` just covers the situation where the Parameter is not provided.

```
<mycomponent Test="MyTest">

</mycomponent>

@code {

  private TestBase MyTest = new TestBase() {Cap = "Test Value"};

  SomeButtonClick Event() 
  {
    MyTest.Value = "Another Value";
  }
}
```

I suggest you read up about components - [This is a good start](https://blazor-university.com/components/) or [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

### Update

straight answer to your question is: No you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello MrC
Thanks For reply. In my case I cannot set new instance of Testbase class because there are important value in other nested property of Test. Suppose there are multiple parameters in Testbase class like MenuId, sources, cap, and many more

Comment: Your code doesn't show that - I see `public TestBase Test { get; set; } = new TestBase();`.  Where do these new properties come from? Maybe just pass a string containing Cap as a Parameter and set it in the instance of TestBase in the component.  Or move to a Data Service to hold the *shared* data.

Comment: I have single parameters in Testbase class is only for test purpose. Now I have updated my original question. Please see it

Comment: Looks like you need to put `TestBase` into a data service.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got you. I just want to know that ,is there a way to pass value in nested parameters from razor class ?

Comment: No you can't do what your trying to do.